# How can I store SSRS reports in Git for use with Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, github, reporting-services, continuous-integration

My team has recently switched from TFS/Team City to Git/Azure DevOps, and we want to include our published reports with our new CI/CD pipeline.

We haven't had our reports integrated in this manner before; we had the stored procedures included with our database projects, but the report definition files (RDLs) were manually deployed to the report server. I've found how to build the pipeline in Azure DevOps, but I'm not sure how we would migrate the RDLs over to Github. Is it as simple as just making a new solution in there, or is it more complex?

Comment: Are your reports in a Visual Studio report project? If so, here's an example [GitHub SSRS Example](https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples)

Comment: That's part of what we're trying to figure out is how to organize the projects. We've got 2 ideas right now: one project for each report or one project for all reports. I favor organizing it so that the reports are grouped in projects by types or use cases.

Comment: At my company, we organised our reports with one solution with multiple projects by discipline e.g. human resources, finance, information technology, etc. Then we created active directory groups per folder to assign users.

Comment: Also, I recommend using a database user as a service account to run the reports, so the only permission the user needs is the AD group.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty helpful. The only big issue we have is that several of our reports are cross-used. I'm going to recommend we build a "cross" project for reports that are multi-use

Answer (score 0):

What we did was download the reports into XML files then push them up into a git repo.

this creates nice subset of folder and XML files for every report from the catalog

```
--select * from #ReportDetails
--drop table #ReportDetails
-- select * from #Temp
-- drop table #Temp

DECLARE @intFlag INT=1  /*To start with 1 in while loop*/
DECLARE @MaxReportCount INT

Select   ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ItemId) as Report_No,ItemId,Name as Report_name,[Path] as Report_Path,replace(SUBSTRING(PATH,1,LEN(PATH)-(LEN(Name)+1)),'/','\') as Folder_Path
       into #ReportDetails
       from [dbo].[Catalog]
       where [Type]=2 /*Load all the reports (Type=2 indicates) from catalog table to table variable*/
select @MaxReportCount = MAX(Report_No) from #ReportDetails /*Get max count to pass as highest value in while loop*/

-- options to download spacific reports or folders. 
--delete from #ReportDetails 
    --where Folder_Path <> '\C3 Reports'
    --where  Report_name <> 'Care Message Referrals and Diagnostics'

     Declare @FolderContainer AS NVARCHAR(200)
     declare @cmd as varchar(MAX) /*Hold xml file for report*/
     declare @Reportqueryout as varchar (240) /*Hold report output path*/
     declare @DynamicQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX) /*Hold xp_cmdshell string for generating RDL file*/

WHILE (@intFlag <= @MaxReportCount)  /*Declare loop to generate rdl file of all reports one by one*/
BEGIN
    
     Select @FolderContainer='<add local folder here drive here>'+Folder_Path from #ReportDetails where Report_No=@intFlag

     Select @cmd =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),  
           CASE       
             WHEN LEFT(C.Content,3) = 0xEFBBBF THEN STUFF(C.Content,1,3,'''')        
             ELSE C.Content        END) 
     FROM  '<add report database here>'.[dbo].[Catalog] CL
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),CL.Content) Content) C  WHERE  CL.ItemID =
               (Select ItemId from #ReportDetails
     where Report_No=@intFlag)

     select * into #Temp from (select @cmd temp) a /*store XML file to temp table*/
       ------------------------------------
      
        EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @FolderContainer
   
     --  ------------------------------------
        select @Reportqueryout= '"'+@FolderContainer+'\'+Report_name+'.rdl"'
     from #ReportDetails
     where  Report_No=@intFlag /*Generate output path */

     select @DynamicQuery='EXEC master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp " '
                           + 'Select Temp from #Temp" QUERYOUT '
                           + @Reportqueryout
                           + ' -c   -T''' /* Here Localhost\reportinstance  is the SQL server name with instance*/

     EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @DynamicQuery
           
     Drop table #Temp
        set @FolderContainer=''
        set @cmd=''
        set @Reportqueryout=''
        set @DynamicQuery=''

     SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1 /*By increasing this go to or fetch next report*/
      

END
```